# Is there any way to swap editors between tabs / customize tabs in the 3d view tool shelf (the "T" bar)?

Tags: interface, add-on, customization

For example, if I could move all editors/panels such as the highlighted (Bevel Curve Tools) into one "Addon" tab, or just move the editors/panels around in general that would be great. There's a whole bunch of tabs in there that I would really like to consolidate; I'd rather not have to turn my addons on and off just to declutter the workspace.

[image: Blender 3d view with the "Bevel Curve Tools" editor/panel in the Tool Shelf highlighted]